# Finding the basis of the image and kernel of $T(X)= X-X^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the basis and dimension of the kernel and image of $$T:M_n(\mathbb R)\to M_n(\mathbb R)\\  T(X)= X-X^t$$

Looking for $\ker T$, we have $T(X)=0$ so $X=X^t$ which is a symmetric matrix. The the dimension of the basis of a symmetric matrix is $\frac {n(n-1)} 2$ since we count only the elements below the diagonal including the diagonal.

From here I can find: $\dim Im T+ \frac {n(n-1)} 2 = n^2$ so $\dim Im T = \frac {n(n+1)} 2 $.

But how can I represent the basis of the image and kernel here?

Comment: For the kernel, take a basis of the symmetric matrices ($a_{ij} = e_{ij} + e_{ji}$ works). For the image, complete that base (for example take all $e_{ij}$ below diagonal singularly). Anyway I think you got the numbers mixed up, thinking about $2x2$ matrices symmetric matrices have dimension $n(n+1)/2 = 3$

Comment: Yeah you're right about the counting. So we can represent the basis like a function with cases? @AnalysisStudent0414

Comment: Wait, I'll write a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $E_{ij}$ as a basis of $n\times n$ matrices (the standard one), with $1$ at $i$-row, $j$-column and $0$ anywhere else. 
For example $E_{13}$ in $3\times 3$ matrices is $E_{13} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 &1 \\ 0 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &0\end{pmatrix}$

Now a basis of symmetric matrices can be written as $E_{ii} \cup (F_{ij} = E_{ij} + E_{ji})_{i<j} $, meaning that basically we consider just the elements below and in the diagonal. If we count, those are $$\displaystyle n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Now to get a basis of $\operatorname{Im} T$ you can complete the basis of $\ker T$ to a basis of the whole $n \times n$ matrices. To do so, ask yourself hwo can you get the standard basis from the symmetric basis, and the answer is simple: you need to "separate" the terms $F_{ij}$. So add $(G_{ij}=E_{ij})_{i<j}$ (and those are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ as intended. 
Now every element of the standard basis can be written as a linear combination of elements from the basis of $\operatorname{Im}T$ and $\ker T$.

$$E_{ii} = E_{ii}$$
$$E_{ij} = G_{ij}\quad (i < j)$$
$$E_{ij} = G_{ij} - F_{ij}\quad (i>j)$$

So you're done.